# Setting a height in CSS for an unordered list?

Tags: css

I've got a list here for my page's footer, that I want displayed horizontally.

But because I've turned it into an inline list to go horizontally, the background images get cut off vertically. The biggest one is 27px high.

So I'm stuck.. I know why the following is doing what it's doing. But how do I get around it?

Here's the html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul>
        <li id="footer-tmdb"><a href="">Film data courtesy of TMDB</a></li>
        <li id="footer-email"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li id="footer-twitter"><a href="">Follow Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#footer ul {
    height: 27px;
}

#footer ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#footer-tmdb {
    background: url('../images/logo-tmdb.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left: 140px;
}

#footer-email {
    background: url('../images/icon-email.png') no-repeat 0 3px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#footer-twitter {
    background: url('../images/icon-twitter.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left: 49px;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: footer]

As you can see, half of the images are cut off.

The simpler the solution, the better, please.

Comment: `#footer ul {
    height: 27px;float:left
}` otherwise give the height to the `li`

Comment: Thanks everyone. I went with Joshua's version in the end

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#footer ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 27px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `inline-block`

```
#footer li {
  height: 27px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but won't work in IE7, if that's important. ( http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html )

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid that if I could unfortunately

Comment: You could always use [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) to take away the pain :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#footer ul {
    overflow: auto
}

#footer ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#footer li,
#footer ul {
    height: 27px;
}
```